# Invalid JSON output with curl in bash while crawling webpages

Tags: json, macos, bash

I'm building a crawler in bash which crawls webpages and sends the html to an api. The api expects valid `json`.

There are a lot of webpages with content like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/contrib/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

I use curl to download the pages

```bash
curl -s --cookie "$cookie_content" "$crawl_url" -o "$PWD/temp/curl.txt"
```

This what I have for encoding the response:

```bash
body=`cat "$PWD/temp/curl.txt"`
body=`printf "%q" "$body"`
body=`echo ${body:2:${#body} - 3}` # this removes the $ and the ' around the string
```

Escaping the `"` works:

```bash
body=`echo "$body" | LC_ALL=C sed s/\"/'\\\"'/g`
```

But there are still `\'` in the output, that is invalid `json`. And there are possible more invalid `json` characters when there will be more websites I did not test yet.

How to make every webpage convert to valid `json`?

Possible result could be something like:

```js
{
  "crawledAt": "2015-07-20...",
  "page": {
    "content": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using something other than `bash` (like Python or Ruby, for example) that has actual JSON parsing and generation tools?

Comment: Thats actually a good idea. Didn't know Python before, but managed it in 1 hour. Thanks for the tip!